# UITabBarController UITabBarItems placed on the left but one on the right

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to place all UITabBarItems of my UITabBarController on the left but one on the right. Any idea to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would instantiate a UITabBarItem with nil for title and image and a tag with a value out of range.

```
UITabBarItem *flexItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil image:nil tag:999];
```

Then add these to your items array to create the effect you wish.

```
aTabBar.items = @[item1, item2, flexItem, flexItem, item3];
```

In the tabBar:didSelectItem: callback add a switch case to handle your items and let the flexItem's fall through the default case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flexible space between the last item on the left and the item on the right.

```
NSMutableArray *itemArray [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Add items to the left
...

// Add flexible item to push everything else to the right
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] inithWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
        target:nil
        action:nil];
[itemArray addObject:flexItem];
[flexItem release];

// Add items to the right
...

self.toolbarItems = itemArray;
[itemArray release];
```

Comment: It seems impossible to edit UITabBar of an UITabBarController. The property is readonly

Comment: Oh Sorry. I was thinking Toolbar not Tabbar. I have done what you are talking about by adding empty tabs to the tabbar. You can use the UITabbarContollerDelegate method tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: and return NO for the empty tabs.

Comment: It seems to be the only possible solution before UIViewContainers era